# Split a BibTeX author field into parts

Tags: raku

I am trying to parse a BibTeX author field using the following grammar:

```
use v6;
use Grammar::Tracer;

# Extract BibTeX author parts from string. The parts are separated
# by a comma and optional space around the comma
grammar Author {
    token TOP {
        <all-text> 
    }
    token all-text {
        [<author-part> [[\s* ',' \s*] || [\s* $]]]+ 
    }
    token author-part { 
        [<-[\s,]> || [\s* <!before ','>]]+
    }
}

my $str = "Rockhold, Mark L";
my $result = Author.parse( $str );
say $result;
```

**Output**:

```
TOP
|  all-text
|  |  author-part
|  |  * MATCH "Rockhold"
|  |  author-part
```

But here the program hangs (I have to press CTRL-C) to abort.
I suspect the problem is related to the negative lookahead assertion. I tried to remove it, and then the program does not hang anymore, but then I am also not able to extract the last part `"Mark L"` with an internal space.

Note that for debugging purposes, the `Author` grammar above is a simplified version of the one used in my actual program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `[\s* <!before ','>]` may not make any progress. Since it's in a quantifier, it will be retried again and again (but not move forward), resulting in the hang observed.

Such a construct will reliably hang at the end of the string; doing `[\s* <!before ',' || $>]` fixes it by making the lookahead fail at the end of the string also (being at the end of the string is a valid way to not be before a `,`).

At least for this simple example, it looks like the whole `author-part` token could just be `<-[,]>+`, but perhaps that's an oversimplification for the real problem that this was reduced from.

Glancing at `all-text`, I'd also point out the [% quantifier modifier](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_%2525-regex_%2525%2525-Modified_quantifier%3A_%2525%2C_%2525%2525) which makes matching comma-separated (or anything-separated, really) things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! It seems that you also can fix the problem by using `\s+` instead of `\s*` in the expression? So the problem is that the expression must match at least one character, or else it will just get stuck?

Comment: Yes, the principle is that to get out of the quantifier loop, at some point the quantified thing must fail to match. `\s+` is one way to force a failure to match to occur.